# Can one set the text colour for a wxMenuItem in Python?

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, wxwidgets

Looking at the [wxWidgets documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxmenuitem.html#wxmenuitem), I see that one should be able to set the text colour for a wxMenuItem object in Windows only.  I am using Windows, so good.

When coding in wxPython and trying to accomplish this, not only do I not get the menu item's text colour changed, but I notice that the menu item which follows this menu item in the same menu gets indented by 1 character.  Very strange indeed. Should I remove the directive to set the text colour, the two menu items line up as expected.

So here is my code.  I don't see any mistakes in my code, but perhaps there is something because I am sure that indentation is a sign something is up.

```
menu = wx.Menu()
colour = (255,0,0) # like the text to be red
m_cluster = menu.Append(-1, "&Cluster\tAlt-C", "Cluster Options.")
m_cluster.SetTextColour(colour) # remembered to spell color with u
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OpenClusterDialog, m_cluster)
m_data = menu.Append(-1, "Data Source", "Set Data Source Information")
self.Bind(ex.EVT_MENU, self.OpenDataSourceDialog, m_data)
menuBar.Append(menu, "&Options") # menu bar previously defined
```

`wxversion.py` reports that I have `2.8-msv-unicode` installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with your code and noticed that the color will only be applied if the menuitem is not yet appended to the menu. So instead of `menu.Append(...)`, you need to to:

```
m_cluster = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, "&Cluster\tAlt-C", "Cluster Options.")
m_cluster.SetTextColour(colour)
menu.AppendItem(m_cluster)
```

I'm on wx 2.9 so YMMV. I did not notice the indentation problem, but that can also be related to the version.

[image: Red menu item]

Comment: Great!  Works for me too.  Just was doing things in the wrong order / doing things too compactly